# disable all future month in select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 3 select tags which displays the date/month/year, i am currently showing the list of years to current year i.e 2017 i want the same to work with moth. Below is my javascript code which i am using for year

```
<select name="month" >
  <option value="">select</option>
</select>
<select name="day" >
  <option value="">select</option>
</select>

<select name="year">
  <option value="">select</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getFullYear();
    for (var i = n; i >= 1950; i--) {
        var opt = new Option();
        opt.value = opt.text = i;
        kcyear.add(opt);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where is the javascript code?

Comment: Javascript is only what i want

Comment: You may use datepicker....Do you want to use it?

Comment: Try using some datepicker  plugin

Comment: @orbit i dont wanna use datepicker as i have 3 different select tags.

Comment: @AlivetoDie not duplicate because i have already tried that method but not working in my condition

Comment: @Arsee  i said possible duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is how I would make it. [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/flosommerfeld/kxvfvyr6/2) for a jsfiddle

I am looping through each option element and check if the value attribute is bigger than the current month value. If it is I hide that element.

```
<select name="month">
  <option selected value="">select</option>
  <option value='1'>January</option>
  <option value='2'>February</option>
  <option value='3'>March</option>
  <option value='4'>April</option>
  <option value='5'>May</option>
  <option value='6'>June</option>
  <option value='7'>July</option>
  <option value='8'>August</option>
  <option value='9'>September</option>
  <option value='10'>October</option>
  <option value='11'>November</option>
  <option value='12'>December</option>
</select>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  $("option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() > currentMonth) {
      $(this).css("display", "none");
    }
  });
</script>
```